# Why do I get "no url found for submodule path" by using sourcetree?

Tags: git

When I tried to clone project, why I get the error like this :

[image]

It was said that no url found for submodule path in `.gitmodules`

Anyway, where is the location file of `.gitmodules`? How to fix the error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As the [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules) says (emphasis mine):

> The .gitmodules file, *located in the top-level directory of a Git working tree*, is a text file with a syntax matching the requirements of git-config.

So if your repository is in `C:\Users\Asus\Documents\PDA`, the file should be in `C:\Users\Asus\Documents\PDA\.gitmodules`.

Submodules have a path an a URL; it appears your file defines a submodule without URL. You may want to edit the file to either remove the submodule or add a URL.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue.

This is what you can do: Check if you have some `.gitmodules` directory somewhere within your repo. If you have no submodules, delete .gitmodules, and any references to submodules in `.git/config`.

You can check that with following commands:

```sh
bash-3.2$ cd .git
bash-3.2$ find . |grep odules
bash-3.2$ grep -i odules config
```

If that doesn't work and you can't find any submodule do this:

```
bash-3.2$ git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
         160000 b06580880c5eaf8b1564f74c30d595bc6a363a13 0 APPNAME
```

Then

```
bash-3.2$ git rm --cached APPNAME
```